# Create branch at specific starting point but keep same remote tracking branch

Tags: git

I want to create a new branch at `HEAD`, keeping the same remote tracking branch as the branch I'm currently on, then check out the new branch. This is the command I'm trying to use:

```
$ git checkout --track @{upstream} -b feature/cleanup-gradle HEAD
fatal: 'HEAD' is not a commit and a branch 'feature/cleanup-gradle' cannot be created from it
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting the error above. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Have you tried doing it in two steps?

Comment: I realize I could do it in 2 steps, but the point of my question here is to see if I can avoid that.

Comment: There's something _seriously_ screwy about your repository.  Just being an empty repo won't do it, HEAD points to something that is not a commit.  There's no way to get that with ordinary commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a simple alias that solves this problem:

```
cob = "!f() { : git branch ; git checkout -b \"$@\" && git branch -u @{-1}@{upstream}; }; f"
```

Usage (on `master` which tracks `origin/master`):

```
$ git cob topic1
```

Result:

```
Switched to a new branch 'topic1'
Branch topic1 set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently (based on the error), not with any existing Git command.  You can of course write your own Git command, though.  Place the script below in a location in which it will be executable (I use `$HOME/scripts/` for such things), call it `git-nbranch`, make sure that it *is* executable, and run `git nbranch`:

```
$ git nbranch
usage: git nbranch [options] newname

    Create new branch but set its upstream to the current branch's upstream.

    If and when this succeeds, you're on the new branch.

    -s, --start ...       starting commit for new branch (default HEAD)
```

This script illustrates some of the techniques that can be be used to write Git commands.

```
#! /bin/sh

OPTIONS_KEEPDASHDASH=
OPTIONS_STUCKLONG=
OPTIONS_SPEC="git nbranch [options] newname

Create new branch but set its upstream to the current branch's upstream.

If and when this succeeds, you're on the new branch.
--
s,start=  starting commit for new branch (default HEAD)
"

# parse options (defined above) and obtain "fatal" function etc.
. git-sh-setup

start=HEAD
while :; do
    case "$1" in
    --) shift; break;;
    -s) start="$2"; shift 2;;
    esac
done

case $# in 1) ;; *) usage; esac

# optional - we can just let git checkout -b check later
#ref=$(git check-ref-format --normalize "refs/heads/$1") ||
#    die "fatal: $1 is not a valid branch name"
#ref=${ref#refs/heads/} # make suitable for -b
ref="$1"

# compute settings
curbranch=$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD) ||
    die "fatal: not on a branch"
case "$start" in
    HEAD) startrev=$(git rev-parse -q --verify HEAD) ||
    die "fatal: current branch does not exist yet";;
    *) startrev=$(git rev-parse -q --verify "$start"^{commit}) ||
    die "fatal: $start does not name an existing commit";;
esac
remote=$(git config --get branch.$curbranch.remote) ||
    die "fatal: current branch $curbranch has no remote"
merge=$(git config --get branch.$curbranch.merge) ||
    die "fatal: current branch $curbranch has no upstream"

git checkout -b "$ref" "$startrev" ||
    die "fatal: unable to create and switch to $ref"
git config branch."$ref".remote "$remote" &&
git config branch."$ref".merge "$merge"
```

Answer (score 1):

`HEAD` does point to a commit. The confusion is due to a semantic error in the arguments and a git bug, both explained at
https://marc.info/?m=159008858830234. From that message:

```
[…] you can't do what you want with a single checkout command. I think:

  git checkout -b work HEAD
  git branch --set-upstream-to=master
```

Answer (score 0):

The [discussion mentioned in the git mailing list](https://marc.info/?m=159008858830234) by [Dana Dahlstrom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10869154/dana-dahlstrom)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61942886/6309) has led to a fix in Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), since the error message from "`git checkout -b foo -t bar baz`" was confusing.

See [commit bb2198f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb2198fb91ada94cfc6f8ec81b9dadcf3959fe10), [commit 16ab794](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16ab794b8257dd08906994d5cccacfa3886aa543) (24 May 2020) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit de82fb4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de82fb45db72fb425fd5d4af81955e48349c2816), 02 Jun 2020)</sup>

> ### [`checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb2198fb91ada94cfc6f8ec81b9dadcf3959fe10): improve error messages for `-b` with extra argument
>
> <sup>Original-patch-by: Jeff King</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>
>
> When we try to create a branch "`foo`" based on "`origin/master`" and give `git checkout -b` an extra unsupported argument "`bar`", it confusingly reports:
>
> ```
> $ git checkout -b foo origin/master bar
> fatal: 'bar' is not a commit and a branch 'foo' cannot be created from it
>
> $ git checkout --track -b foo origin/master bar
> fatal: 'bar' is not a commit and a branch 'foo' cannot be created from it
> ```
>
> That's wrong, because it very well understands that "`origin/master`" is supposed to be the start point for the new branch and not "`bar`".
>
> Check if we got a commit and show more fitting messages in that case instead:
>
> ```
> $ git checkout -b foo origin/master bar
> fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'foo' at the same time.
>
> $ git checkout --track -b foo origin/master bar
> fatal: '--track' cannot be used with updating paths
> ```

Comment: I don't know if I'd really call this an answer to my question since I actually want my use case to work. But the semantics haven't changed at all, they just make it fail "better". But I guess, if nothing else, this change makes it clear they don't intend to support my use case. Since my original question, I've been using an alias that runs this in 2 steps.

Comment: I do appreciate the information though, so thank you for that!

Answer (score -1):

Just take the explicit `HEAD` off:

```
$ git checkout --track @{u} -b new
Branch 'new' set up to track remote branch 'next' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'new'
$
```

`git checkout` without specifying a commit or paths is a no-op except for option effects, which is what you want.  That said, the error you're getting could certainly be better.

Comment: I already tried that. It creates a branch using `@{u}` as a starting point in this example. So it is not using `HEAD`.